# Issue when trying to select one checkbox inside v-for in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<div id="example-1">
  <ul>
    <input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="Filter" />
    <p>sortKey = {{sortKey}}</p>
    <li v-for="item in sortedItems">
      <input class="checkbox-align" type="checkbox" :value="item.name" id="productname" v-model="checked" /> {{ item.price }} - {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cecont" v-if="!checked">
    <p>text content</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

With the above code in codepen, I am able to perfom task like, on clicking on checkbox the content should be hidden. Where i am able to achieve it. But problem is, on clicking of one checkbox, I am able to select multiple checkboxes.

So resolve this issue,  Do i need to add id attribute  to input??

or change my v-model attribute, and if i change my v-model to checked.name functionality not working.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: your v-model `checked` should be part of an array. Right now its single key for all checkboxes in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `checked` property to individual item

You are creating multiple `checkboxes` with all having the same `v-model` value, which is `checked`. If any one of the `checkboxes` is checked, all the `checkboxes` will be checked together.

**Solution.**

You should set the `checked` property to each item in the loop. This will make the `v-model` work independently.

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    // sort: item,
    sortKey: 'name',
    checked: false,
    searchString: "",
    items: [
      { price: '1', name: 'mm', checked: false },
      { price: '22', name: 'aa', checked: false },
      { price: '55', name: 'dd', checked: false },
      { price: '77', name: 'gg', checked: false },
      { price: '123', name: 'kk', checked: false },
      { price: '53', name: 'mn', checked: false },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    checkedLength() {
      return checkedLength = this.items.filter(item => item.checked === true).length;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example-1">
  <ul>
    <input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="Filter" />
    <p>sortKey = {{sortKey}}</p>
    <li v-for="item in items">
      <input class="checkbox-align" type="checkbox" :value="item.name" id="productname" v-model="item.checked" /> {{ item.price }} - {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p> checkedLength {{checkedLength}}</p>
  <div class="cecont" v-if="checkedLength > 0">
    <p>text content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sundar `v-if="!checked"` will also change. You need to figure out for which checkbox you need to show the div

Comment: @Sundar so call a function that checks your `items` array for checked in `v-if`

Comment: @Sundar I have made a small change in that logic, I have made the condition to show the text as a computed property. This wil be the better approach.